# how to get table row content using php onclick of row

Tags: php, html, session

I want to get content of particular row after clicking on particular row and store it in session and send to another php file for further processing.

```
foreach ($employee as $key => $value) { 
echo "
<tr>
   <td >".$value->id."</td>
   <td >".$value->name."</td>
</tr>
";
}
```

Comment: According to your given code, you've already got data in ```$employee``` variable. Can you bit explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: You may use $.each function in jquery after that for sending data into another php file use Ajax

Comment: use anchor tag <td><a href="destination_page.php?id=<?=$value->id?>"></a</td> on destination page you can get the clicked row unique id .you can do further process there .

Comment: i got data which i am storing in table but when i click on particular row i want id of particular row and send to another page. onclicking i want to redirect my page according to id using php @mi6crazyheart

Comment: @JYoThI but i want data after click on row not only cell

Comment: you will get  unique id on next page so you can fetch it from database again using id with select .....where id=$_GET[id];

Comment: @ JYoThI i want to send id to one page and redirect to another page ex-destinatio_page. the id which is receiving is included in destination_page.

Comment: i don't want to show my id in url how it is possible

Comment: Just encrypt those values & send in GET.

Answer (score 2):

Check this sample example. Hope it'll help you to move forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $( ".tblRows" ).click(function() {
        var row_data = $(this).attr("data");
        alert(row_data);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $employee[] = array('id'=>'111', 'name'=>'Mango');
    $employee[] = array('id'=>'222', 'name'=>'Apple');

    echo '<table border=1>';
    foreach ($employee as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr class='tblRows' data='".$value['id']."-".$value['name']."'>";
            echo "<td>".$value['id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['name']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know how to fetch cell values using jQuery. but i want it in php.and i have to redirect page using these cell values

Comment: After getting those values by Javascript redirect to one PHP file. Then store those data in SESSION variable. Ex - ```window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/hello.php?data=111-222";```

Comment: Send by GET. See my previous comment for example.

Comment: but, i am redirecting to one page i.e desination page. and data i am sending is another page which i was included in destination page. how can i do please give me some idea.

Comment: If your destination page is ```destination.php``` & you have an another page ```another.php``` which has included(belive used PHP include() method ) in destination.php``` then also you can get those $_GET data in both the pages.